# Asking a business contact to make a request on my behalf?

Tags: politeness, english-to-japanese, phrase-requests, keigo

I am helping to plan an event featuring the work of a Japanese artist. I'm speaking to his representative, and would like to ask the question,

> Can you ask (name) if he would be willing to write a short statement to the public about this event?

but I'm not sure what the most polite way to phrase that would be.

This is what I have written now, but I'm not sure if it's correct:

> Aさんがこのイベントについての公式声明を発表した場合大変助かります。それについて聞いていただけますか？

Answer (score 2):

When making your request in conversation, I think that it will not finish with one phrase.
I'll write the conversation that I assume below.
A is you and B is the representative of the artist.

Ａ：「はじめまして。Ｘさん/Ｘ先生｛せんせい｝の representative をされている方｛かた｝ですよね。」
Ｂ：「そうですが...。何｛なに｝か？」
Ａ：「私｛わたし｝は、（名刺｛めいし｝を渡｛わた｝しながら）こう言｛い｝う者｛もの｝です。この度｛たび｝のＸさん/Ｘ先生｛せんせい｝の作品展示｛さくひんてんじ｝イベントのお手伝｛てつだ｝いをしている者｛もの｝です。」
Ｂ：「それは、どうも。」
Ａ：「ところで、このイベントのパンフレットにＸさん/Ｘ先生｛せんせい｝のお言葉｛ことば｝を載｛の｝せたいと思｛おも｝っているのですが、是非｛ぜひ｝ともあなた様｛さま｝から先生｛せんせい｝にお願｛ねが｝いしていただけないでしょうか」
Ｂ：「どのぐらいの分量｛ぶんりょう｝ですか？」
Ａ：「（パンフレットのレイアウトを見｛み｝せながら、）ここのところに載｛の｝せたいので、Ｙ文字｛もじ｝ぐらいでしょうか。」
Ｂ：「依頼｛いらい｝の内容｛ないよう｝は分｛わ｝かりました。即答｛そくとう｝はできませんがお待｛ま｝ちいただけますか。」
Ａ：「はい。ありがとうございます。」
Ｂ：「持｛も｝ち帰｛かえ｝って、のちほど連絡｛れんらく｝します。連絡先｛れんらくさき｝は、名刺｛めいし｝に書｛か｝かれているここでいいですか。」
Ａ：「はい、そうです。出来｛でき｝ればメール/携帯電話｛けいたいでんわ｝でお願｛ねが｝いします。」
Ｂ：「（名刺｛めいし｝を出｛だ｝しながら）何｛なに｝かあったらここに連絡｛れんらく｝ください。」
Ａ：「突然｛とつぜん｝のお願｛ねが｝いですみません。よろしくお願｛ねが｝い致｛いた｝します。」

I don't think that the conversation will proceed as assumed above.
Therefore, I think that it is better to request it properly by a letter or by a document. In this case, you can request it in English.

Well, if you have an appropriate person to whom you can ask to translate the request in English to Japanese by your side, I think, it is easier to ask that person for making this request in place of you without asking for the translation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice, and for providing this helpful scenario! Being new to this site, I think I formatted my question incorrectly. I apologize for the confusion, but the conversation you wrote is still an excellent resource for future reference! :)

Comment: ask for ~ request はおかしいです・・・ make a request を使ったほうがいいと思います・・「相手」という意味でしょうけど opponent もおかしいです・・・